# Replace last character in specific column with value 0

Tags: linux, awk, gawk

How to replace the last character in column 2 with value 0

input

```
1232;1001;1 
2231;2007;1
2234;2009;2
2003;1114;1
```

output desired

```
1232;1000;1 
2231;2000;1
2234;2000;2
2003;1110;1
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried so we can help you debug it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not necessarily better, but a mathematical approach for numerical data...

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"} {$2=int($2/10)*10}1'
```

round down the last digits (ones), to round down two digits (ones and tens) replace `10` with `100`.

Or, simple replacement is easier with GNU `sed`

```
$ sed 's/.;/0;/2'
```

Answer (score 2):

### Modifying Input with `gensub()`

You can use any number of GNU awk [string functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) to do this, but the gensub() command is particularly useful. It has the signature:

> gensub(regexp, replacement, how [, target])

which makes it extremely flexible for these sorts of transformations.

## Converting Your Example

```
# Store your input in a shell variable for MCVE convenience, although
# you can have this data in a file or pass it on standard input if you
# prefer.
example_input='1232;1001;1 
2231;2007;1
2234;2009;2
2003;1114;1'

# Use awk's gensub() string function.
echo "$example_input" | awk '{print gensub(/.;/, "0;", 2, $1)}'
```

This results in the following output:

> ```
> 1232;1000;1
> 2231;2000;1
> 2234;2000;2
> 2003;1110;1
> ```

Comment: `$1` is not necessary (note that here it's the same as `$0` and implied).

Comment: @karakfa While it's optional, it helps to clarify the target, and explains to future visitors where they can make changes to the target string to be modified. SO isn't just about helping the OP; it's also about making the answers useful to future visitors. YMMV.

Answer (score 1):

**`awk`** approach:

```
awk -F';' '{ sub(/.$/,0,$2) }1' OFS=';' file
```

The output:

```
1232;1000;1 
2231;2000;1
2234;2000;2
2003;1110;1
```

---

Or the same with `substr()` function:

```
awk -F';' '{ $2=substr($2,0,3)0 }1' OFS=';' file
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do that with `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/^\([^;]*;[^;]*\).;/\10;/' filename
```